# Wrong output for binary search for extreme elements in a sorted array

Tags: c++, binary-search

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int bsearch(int x, int lo, int hi, int a[])
{
    if(lo <= hi) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
        if(x == a[mid]) {
            cout<<mid<<endl;
           return mid;
        } else if(x < a[mid]) {
            hi = mid - 1;
            bsearch(x, lo, hi, a);
        } else {
            lo = mid + 1;
            bsearch(x, lo, hi, a);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

main()
{
    int a[5] = {12, 13, 15, 18, 20};
    cout << bsearch(20, 0, 4, a);
}
```

The above is an implementation of binary search in C++. I wrote a function to perform binary search that takes in a sorted array as input. Inside the main function, I have passed an array of sorted integers as an argument to the function. The program seems to work fine when I search for an element not located at the extreme ends of the array, but gives wrong output for extreme elements. To find out the error, I included a "cout" statement within the function body to print out the value of 'mid'. Surprisingly, the value of mid is calculated correctly, even in the case of elements at extremes of the array, but the output of the program is still wrong for extreme elements. Can anyone point out what is wrong with it?

Comment: You should do some *more* debugging.  Step through the whole thing to find out which calculation went wrong.

Comment: You make all these recursive calls to `bsearch`, then discard their result. The top-level call (the one from `main`) then falls through to `return -1;`. The two recursive call should be `return bsearch(...);`

Comment: You should place a `return` with the recursive calls: `return bsearch(x, lo, hi, a);`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing return statement in lines with recursive calls to bsearch function.

This seems to work:

```
int bsearch(int x, int lo, int hi, int a[])
{
    if(lo <= hi)
    {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
        if(x == a[mid])
        {
           return mid;
        }
        else if(x < a[mid])
        {
            hi = mid - 1;
            return bsearch(x, lo, hi, a);
        }
        else
        {
            lo = mid + 1;
            return bsearch(x, lo, hi, a);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with my understanding of recursive calls. Just to be clear, the return statement in a recursively called function transfers the control to the program that called it, right? (And here I assumed it would return control to the 'main' function.)